# How to evade singularity or stiff system suspected in NDsolve?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, nonlinear, singularity

I need to integrate my ODE between $t=10^{-29} s$ to $t=10^{-20} s$, so I did;

```
Ba=-8.597*10^65 ψ[t] (1 - 2.90799*10^-87 ψ[t]^2)-(1.2675*10^124 t^(4/3) 
    ψ[t])/(1 + 2.9079917009173806522983649735*10^-87 ψ[t]^2)^2 + 3.9*10^62 
    t^(2/3)ψ'[t] + ψ''[t]
sols = NDSolve[{Ba == 0, ψ[10^(-30)] ==1.85*10^(43), ψ'[10^(-30)] == 0 }, 
    {ψ}, {t, 1*10^(-29),10^(2)}, 
    Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching","NonstiffTest" -> False}]
```

But, I get the error:

```
NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 9.999999999999999`*^-31, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.
```

I'm trying to start my integration from $t=1*10^{-29} s$, but Mathematica starts it at $t=0$.

Using [Wolfram website](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveOverview.html) for Help, I got no solution to my problem. I need to force Mathematica starts the integration at $t=1*10^{-29} s$, evading the singularity.

Comment: It's not possible, because your initial condition is given at `10^-30`, so the integration will always start from here. Also, notice `NDSolve` has actually managed to find the solution between `{1.*10^-29, 1.*10^-30}`.

Comment: To what singularity are you referring in the question?

Comment: @xzczd, I understand it, but it is very strange, my system is singular for all initial condition. There is a way to analyse it?

Comment: @bbgodfrey, the singularity at the initial condition $t == 9.999999999999999`*^{-31}$. But, looks like my system is singular everywhere.

Comment: Evaluating `Ba` for the initial conditions, `Ba /. t -> 10^-30 /. {ψ[10^-30] -> 1.85*10^43, `ψ'[10^-30] -> 0}` yields `-5.89007*10^126 + ψ''[1/1000000000000000000000000000000]`.  Evidently, `NDSolve` immediately interprets this as an indication of stiffness, even though the ODE is not stiff.  I recommend that the ODE variables be rescaled to eliminate the large constants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some progress can be made as follows.  First, as noted in my comment above, evaluating `Ba` at the initial conditions in the question yields

```
(* -5.89007*10^126 + ψ''[1/1000000000000000000000000000000] *)
```

`NDSolve` chokes on the immense constant, immediately claiming that the equation is singular or stiff.  Clearly, it is neither.  However, starting the computation at `t == 0` produces an answer, although not a very good one.

```
sols = NDSolveValue[{Ba == 0, ψ[0] == 1.85*10^43, ψ'[0] == 0}, ψ, {t, 0, 10^2}, 
    Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}, MaxSteps -> 10^6];
```

which stops after `1000000` steps at `t == 1.74307*10^-30`.

```
plts = Plot[sols[t], {t, 0, 1.743 10^-30}]
```

[image]

Since there is nothing strange about the ODE, apart from the large constants, the bizarre oscillations seem likely to be due to precision issues.  So, try

```
Bap = -8597*10^62 ψ[t] (1 - 290799*10^-92 ψ[t]^2) - (12675*10^120 t^(4/3) 
    ψ[t])/(1 + 290799*10^-92 ψ[t]^2)^2 + 39*10^61 t^(2/3) ψ'[t] + ψ''[t];
solp = NDSolveValue[{Bap == 0, ψ[0] == 185*10^41, ψ'[0] == 0}, ψ, {t, 0, 10^2}, 
    Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}, MaxSteps -> 10^6, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

which runs through `1000000` steps slightly sooner, at `t == 1.6710494091551866345*10^-30`.  It also throws a few overflow errors immediately after starting.  Nonetheless, the solution is rather more credible.

```
pltp = Plot[solp[t], {t, 0, 1.671 10^-30}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[plts, pltp]
```

[image]

Evidently, the modestly larger `WorkingPrecision -> 20` is sufficient to eliminate the spurious oscillations shown in the first plot.  Further progress probably can be achieved by rescaling both `ψ` and `t` to move the magnitudes of the constants closer to unity.

Comment: Thank you so much, @bbgodfrey. About rescale $\psi$, I've a huge problem; I need a good precision in integration, because it's the universe expansion, so these datas must agree with the observable today.

Comment: @Kamog  Rescaling will not change the precision, but it may help the computation run faster or take bigger time-steps.  I am amazed such a smooth curve takes so long to compute.

Comment: let me ask a question (i'm really newbie with integrators, sorry); If I rescale my variables using $t$ as $1/m_p$, with $m_{p}=1.86\times10^{43}s^{-1}$, will it just transfer my "singularity" or "stiff" to another point?

Comment: @Kamog  From my perspective, the ODE is neither singular nor stiff.  Instead, `NDSolve` appears to be confused by the enormous constants, which probably trigger the "stiff" diagnosis.  In any case, it is impossible (for me, at least) to say whether scaling out mp will solve things.  Try, and see.